# transitions and animations for a div in React and Tailwind Css

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components

I managed to get the sidebar to appear when clicking the hamburger icon with a transition. But now what I'm trying to achieve is making the transition when the close button is clicked. so far I've tried conditional operations inside the render itself but that didn't work. this last iteration is what I've come up with. any suggestions on how to make this transition? thanks heaps.

**Screenshot sample**

[image]

**Home.jsx**

```
/*
  notes:

  date created: 15/03/2023
*/

import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Sidebar, UserProfile } from '../components';
import Pins from './Pins';
import { client } from '../client';
import myLogo from '../assets/logoCropped.png';
import { userQuery, fetchUserFromLocalStorage } from '../utils/data';
import { HiMenu } from 'react-icons/hi';
import { AiFillCloseCircle } from 'react-icons/ai';
import { Link, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

// TODO: added this along the way. continue doing this until it works
const hiddenSidebar = 'fixed w-1/2 bg-black h-screen overflow-y-auto shadow-md z-10 animate-slide-in duration-75';
const activeSidebar = 'bg-red-500 z-10 transition transition-all ';

const Home = () => {

  const [toggleSideBar, setToggleSideBar] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const scrollRef = useRef(null);

  // const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('user') !== 'undefined' ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user')) : localStorage.clear();
  const userInfo = fetchUserFromLocalStorage();

  // set up scroll to be at the top of the sidebar
  useEffect(() => {
    scrollRef.current.scrollTo(0, 0)
  }, [])

  // retrieve data using a query from data.js
  useEffect(() => {
    // sub is the google id
    const query = userQuery(userInfo?.sub)

    client.fetch(query)
      .then((data) => {
        setUser(data[0]);
      })
  })

  return (
    <div className='flex bg-gray-50 md:flex-row flex-col h-screen transition-height duration-75 ease-out'>

      {/* desktop sidebar */}
      <div className='hidden md:flex h-screen flex-initial'>
        <Sidebar user={user && user} />
      </div>

      {/* mobile sidebar */}
      <div className='flex md:hidden flex-row'>
        <div className='p-2 w-full flex flex-row justify-between items-center shadow-md'>
          <HiMenu fontSize={40} className="cursor-pointer" onClick={() => setToggleSideBar(true)} />
          <Link to='/'>
            <img src={myLogo} alt="logo" className='w-16' />
          </Link>
          <Link to={`user-profile/${user?._id}`}>
            <img src={user?.image} alt="logo" className='w-16' />
          </Link>
        </div>

        {
          toggleSideBar && (
            // TODO: modify this
          <div className={toggleSideBar ? hiddenSidebar : activeSidebar}>
            <div className='absolute w-full flex justify-end items-center p-2 '>
              <AiFillCloseCircle fontSize={30} className="cursor-pointer" onClick={() => 
              {
                setToggleSideBar(false)
              }
                } />
            </div>
            <Sidebar user={user && user} closeToggle={setToggleSideBar} />
          </div>
        )} 
      </div>

      {/* routes */}
      <div className='pb-2 flex-1 h-screen overflow-y-scroll' ref={scrollRef}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="user-profile/:userId" element={<UserProfile />} />
          <Route path='/*' element={<Pins user={user && user} />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>

    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

**tailwind.config.js**

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}', './public/index.html'],
  darkMode: false, // or media or class

  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      margin: {
        320: '320px',
      },
      width: {
        190: '190px',
        275: '275px',
        300: '300px',
        340: '340px',
        350: '350px',
        656: '656px',
        880: '880px',
        508: '508px',
      },
      height: {
        80: '80px',
        340: '340px',
        370: '370px',
        420: '420px',
        510: '510px',
        600: '600px',
        685: '685px',
        800: '800px',
        '90vh': '90vh',
      },
      flex: {
        0.7: '0.7 1 0%',
      },
      maxHeight: {
        370: '370px',
      },

      // further tweeks
      minWidth: {
        210: '210px',
        350: '350px',
        620: '620px',
      },

      // change this for personalization
      textColor: {
        lightGray: '#F1EFEE',
        primary: '#FAFAFA',
        secColor: '#efefef',
        navColor: '#BEBEBE',
      },

      // change this for personalization
      backgroundColor: {
        mainColor: '#FBF8F9',
        secondaryColor: '#F0F0F0',
        blackOverlay: 'rgba(0, 0 ,0 ,0.7)',
      },
      /*
        TODO: create slide-out keyframne and animation config for tailwindcss
        basically a reverse of slide in
      */ 
      keyframes: {
        'slide-in': {
          '0%': {
            '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-200px)',
            transform: 'translateX(-200px)',
          },
          '100%': {
            '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(0px)',
            transform: 'translateX(0px)',
          },
        },
        
        // TODO: added this out
        'slide-out': {
          '0%': {
            '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(0px)',
            transform: 'translateX(0px)',
          },
          '100%': {
            '-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-200px)',
            transform: 'translateX(-200px)',
          },
        },

        'slide-fwd': {
          '0%': {
            '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(0px)',
            transform: 'translateZ(0px)',
          },
          '100%': {
            '-webkit-transform': 'translateZ(160px)',
            transform: 'translateZ(160px)',
          },
        },

        
      },
      animation: {
        'slide-in': 'slide-in 0.5s ease-out',
        'slide-fwd': 'slide-fwd 0.45s cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) both',

        // TODO: added this
        'slide-out' : 'slide-out 0.5s ease-out',
      },
      transitionProperty: {
        height: 'height',
      },
    },
    cursor: {
      'zoom-in': 'zoom-in',
      pointer: "pointer",
    },
  },
  variants: {
    // backgroundColor: ['active']
    extend: {
      
    }
  },


  plugins: [],
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove toggleSideBar && and leave only the change of the className responsible for showing or hiding the menu, when rendering and the value of toggleSideBar is equal to false the component will be disassembled and not show the transition animation.